# .show() doesnt work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am working on this project: http://www.arbamedia.com/test/
if you go to **Dyer dhe dritare** on the left menu and drag one of the elements (the door or the window) into the right side (the desk) in Chrome and FF the 3 options that I have added for that elements show, so this: `$("p", this).show();` works, but in IE9 when I drag an element it doesn't show the the options for dragging, rotating or deleting! I dont know what is wrong.

This is where it happens:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert      : 'invalid', 
  helper      : 'clone',
  containment : 'desk',
  cursorAt    : { left:-11,top:-1 },

  //When first dragged
  stop        : function(ev, ui) {
    /*========================================================================*/
    var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
    var left_   = ev.originalEvent.pageX - $("#desk").position().left;
    var top_    = ev.originalEvent.pageY - $("#desk").position().top;
    // get widht and height of the container div#desk element
    var w_ = $("#desk").width();
    var h_ = $("#desk").height();
    objName  = "#clonediv"+counter++;
    objNamex = "clonediv"+counter;
    $(objName).css({"left":left_,"top":top_});

    var gag =  0;
    $(objName).click(function () {
      $("p", this).show();
      $(this).addClass("selektume");
      $('.rotate_handle').unbind('click');
      $('.rotate_handle').click(function(){
        gag += 45;
        $('.selektume').rotate(gag+'deg');
      });
      $('.delete_handle').click(function() {
        $('.selektume').remove();
      });
      return false;
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
      $("p").hide();
      $(".lgutipT").removeClass("selektume");
    });

    //check if dropped inside the conteiner div#des
    if((left_ >= 0) && (left_ <= w_) && (top_ >= 0) && (top_ <= h_))
    {
      $(objName).css({"left":left_,"top":top_});

      // assign a z-index value
      zindex = left_ + top_;
      $(objName).css({"z-index":zindex});
      $(objName).addClass("lgutipT");
      //$(objName).addClass("ui-widget-content");

      $(objName).removeClass("drag");
      $(objName).append('<p><img class="handler"  src="images/move_button.png"><img class="rotate_handle" src="images/rotate_button.png"><img class="delete_handle" src="images/delete_button.png"></p>');
      $("p", this).show();
    }


    /*========================================================================*/

    //When an existiung object is dragged
    $(objName).draggable({
      containment : "#desk",
      handle      : ".handler",
      cursor      : "move"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: post some of the code that you are working with

Comment: I fixed the indentation on your code. I also removed the escape characters on your strings. I'm not sure why those were there, though. If they are in your actual source file, then that's a problem.

Comment: that is because I returning them with PHP so that is why I am escaping those characters, do you really think thats a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very tricky problem since there's no good documentation on how jQuery UI treats events at a core level. The solution was to unbind and rebind the click event. In IE, the click event is treated differently than other browsers. The solution was simply to rebind the click event after everything is done (1/1000 of a second delay).

My solution was to move the click event, add an unbinding on drag start, and to add a `setTimeout()` on rebinding the `$(document).click()` event listener when drag was complete.

View the source below to view the working solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/AbF6t/

Copy and Paste the HTML to your dev environment.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I just dont understand what should I do with this, how does this help me?: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/guMQa/

Comment: Opps, I copied and pasted the wrong JSFiddle, I updated my post with the correct link. Sorry! http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/AbF6t/

Comment: oh its ok its just that you scared me :) I thought I didnt understand it.. :)

Comment: @MattLo, What do you mean "there's no good documentation on how jQuery UI treats events at a core level"? [the code is commented and open for anyone to read](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.js).

Comment: Documentation meaning at a human read-able level, big picture description. (like jQuery Docs or PHP Docs) It would have taken me an additional hour if I would have read how it works via inline descriptions. Is there a clear definition/description on how jQuery UI treats event bubbling at a cross browser level?